# iOS 8.1 CoreLocationManager requestWhenInUseAuthorization is not prompting AlertView

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, locationmanager

I am trying to use the user location on my iOS app. The app works on iOS 7 but does not in iOS 8.

I tried it all. Read a heap of tutorials and I know that in the iOS 8 we need to call the requestWhenInUseAuthorization method and add the NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription key into Info.plist.

But it still not working, it does not ask user's permission, I am testing in a real device (an iPhone 5c running iOS 8.1.x). I tried to reinstall the app many times.

These are the codes of a very very very smaller project that I created to test this thing.

My ViewController.m

```
#import "ViewController.h"

#import <CoreLocation/CoreLocation.h>

@interface ViewController () <CLLocationManagerDelegate>

@property (strong, nonatomic) CLLocationManager *locationManager;

@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    self.locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
    self.locationManager.delegate = self;

    self.locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest;
    self.locationManager.distanceFilter = kCLHeadingFilterNone;

    if ([self.locationManager respondsToSelector:@selector(requestWhenInUseAuthorization)]) {
        NSLog(@"Pôde chamar o método"); // It could call the method
        [self.locationManager requestWhenInUseAuthorization];
    }

//    [self.locationManager startUpdatingLocation];

}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

#pragma mark - CLLocationManagerDelegate

- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateLocations:(NSArray *)locations {
    NSLog(@"Atualizou Localização para: %@", [locations lastObject]); // Updated the location to
}

- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didFailWithError:(NSError *)error {
    NSLog(@"Location Manager falhou com erro: %@", error); // Location manager failed with error
}

- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didChangeAuthorizationStatus:(CLAuthorizationStatus)status {
    if (status == kCLAuthorizationStatusAuthorized) {
        [self.locationManager startUpdatingLocation];
    }
}

@end
```

My Info.plist

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>CFBundleDevelopmentRegion</key>
    <string>en</string>
    <key>CFBundleExecutable</key>
    <string>$(EXECUTABLE_NAME)</string>
    <key>CFBundleIdentifier</key>
    <string>wallace.$(PRODUCT_NAME:rfc1034identifier)</string>
    <key>CFBundleInfoDictionaryVersion</key>
    <string>6.0</string>
    <key>CFBundleName</key>
    <string>$(PRODUCT_NAME)</string>
    <key>CFBundlePackageType</key>
    <string>BNDL</string>
    <key>CFBundleShortVersionString</key>
    <string>1.0</string>
    <key>CFBundleSignature</key>
    <string>????</string>
    <key>CFBundleVersion</key>
    <string>1</string>

    <key>NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription</key>
    <string></string>


</dict>
</plist>
```

Someone know how to figure this out?

Comment: Just to confirm, does it enter the `if` statement where you request authorization and log the "Pôde chamar o método"? And when you say "it's not working" do you mean that it never asks for authorization? Or it doesn't track location properly? If it simply does not prompt the user, check your settings app to ensure it isn't already authorized and that your location services are turned on.

Comment: The if statement is satisfied.

With "not working" I mean that it does not launch the AlertView asking user's permission. And the locationManager:didChangeAuthorizationStatus: method is called once with status value kCLAuthorizationStatusNotDetermined

Comment: Consider adding a string value to `NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription` in your plist. I think you need to supply text that the user will see when the alert is displayed.

Comment: @Stonz2 I added a text on the string value. But the result is the same

This is the key and value:
    <key>NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription</key>
    <string>Quando em uso</string>

Comment: Not sure what else to tell you- I created a new project and copied your code exactly and it worked first try. If I disable location services on the phone, I'll get `kCLAuthorizationStatusDenied` in the `locationManager:didChangeAuthorizationStatus:` method. If you have location services enabled (Settings -> Privacy -> Location Services) then there is no apparent reason that it shouldn't work.

Comment: @Stonz2 this is very odd. I really don't know what is happening. What is the xCode version of your machine? You tested with iOS 8 device or simulator? Because with iOS 7 it works fine.

I am running xCode 6.1.1

Comment: Created using Xcode 6.1.1 (6A2008a) and tested on an iPhone 5S running iOS 8.1 (12B411). It also worked on the simulator running 8.1

Comment: I had a similar Problem, but it was just a stupid mistake by myself. (Maybe you have done the same mistake, who knows). I edited the plist of the Test-Project with the new entrys and not the actual Project itself.

Answer (score 1):

Add `NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription` and `NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription` to your `Info.plist`. Then you can supply what the AlertView text will be for each of those values.

The location manager will look at the text in those fields to prompt within the AlertView.

Comment: NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription **or** NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription.

Comment: Yeah they're not both required but I usually just include them both anyways.

Comment: It is included. See the end of my Info.plist:
    <key>NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription</key>
    <string></string>

And I tried to add both key values.

Comment: but you don't have a string value in it. You need a string value to represent the text to display

Comment: @aahrens, actually I don't need. This field could be blank.

But just to make ourselves with no doubt I added a string value. The result is the same.

Answer (score 1):

Add the following to the `locationManager:didChangeAuthorizationStatus`:

```
if (status == kCLAuthorizationStatusNotDetermined) {
    [manager requestAlwaysAuthorization];
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I don't know why, but for some reason, adding `NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription` to `info.plist` and calling `requestWhenInUseAuthorization` did not work for me, after several tries I found below solution. Wired but worked for me.

First add both `NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription` and `NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription` keys in `info.plist` and call both methods `requestAlwaysAuthorization` and `requestWhenInUseAuthorization`. Now you should get a notification. Once you get the notification, you can remove unnecessary code and info.plist items.

It worked after several trials, hope it helps atleast for few people.